# Unable to stream RTSP using GStreamer

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to stream RTSP video using GStreamer. I am using `test-launch` example from `gst-rtsp-server`.

Server:

```
./test-launch "(videotestsrc ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay)"
```

Client: VLC.

When I try to open URI `rtsp://0.0.0.0:8554/test` in VLC I've got error:

```
live555 debug: we will now try HTTP tunneling mode
live555 debug: connection error -115
live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
core debug: no access_demux modules matched
core debug: creating access 'rtsp' location='127.0.0.1:8554/test', path='(null)'
core debug: looking for access module matching "rtsp": 25 candidates
core debug: net: connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8554
core debug: connection succeeded (socket = 28)
access_realrtsp debug: rtsp connected
access_realrtsp warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
core debug: no access modules matched
core error: open of `rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test' failed
```

I tried to simple test it with wget and get error `503: Service Unavailable`

gstreamer log:

```
0:00:10.219925652  2772       0xcb4ca0 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:767:find_media: client 0xe140c0: can't prepare media
0:00:10.220158204  2772       0xcb4ca0 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:2283:handle_describe_request: client 0xe140c0: no media
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: is the stream coming from a camera? if so what model? looks like you are just hitting the wrong url for the stream

Comment: For now i just trying using `videotestsrc`, no camera. When I run server it's print this url, so I think it's correct